# issue in executing commands in cmd using C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I am doing two commands in cmd from C# application.

1. renaming a file

   ```
   string commandToExecute;
   commandToExecute = @"/c ren E:\filename filename.rar";
   Process.Start("cmd.exe", commandToExecute);
   ```
2. unrar-ing a file

   ```
   commandToExecute = @"/c unrar e E:\filename.rar";
   Process.Start("cmd.exe", commandToExecute);
   ```

The first part of the code works, but the second part doesn't, although it is working when I write the command in `cmd` manually. And I noticed that when executing in C# it runs the application itself again (like recursion). I don't know why.

Note: I am using 64-bit windows 7.

Comment: You didn't call your program `unrar`, did you?

Comment: unrar isn't my program. It extracts the .rar file

Comment: Shouldn't the file path in the first part `E:\filename filename.rar` be in double quotes, as it contains a space?

Comment: Also I'm assuming unrar takes a switch `e` as per your example, but command line switches like that are usually used `/e` or `-e`, are you sure that's right?

Comment: @Bridge Actually, I think it's two different args. The first one is the path to the original file (which conveniently in this case does not have an extension) and the second argument is the new file name (filename.rar)

Comment: you are missing something. WHEN I COPY THIS COMMEND AND PASTE IT IN CMD, IT RUNS PERFECTLY. IT CAUSES THIS PROBLEM WHEN RUNNING IT USING `Proccess.Start()` .. got me?

Comment: perhaps WE are missing something, or perhaps YOU are not explaining something to us well enough. It's definitely not going to help you get answers to berate commenters.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Yes I think you're right, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that Process.Start launches another process. If the commands need to run serially, you need to obtain a Process object from Process.Start and call the WaitForExit method.